# How to inspect the warnings filter?

Tags: python, filter, warnings

In python, it is possible to change the way warnings are handled by working with the [Warnings Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter). For example, one can add a filter specification to the warnings filter by calling [`warnings.simplefilter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter), by working with the [`PYTHONWARNINGS`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS) environment variable, or by using the [`-W`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w) command-line flag.

How can I inspect the current state of the warnings filter to see what warnings will be filtered, turned into error messages, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `warnings` module maintains a global variable `filters`.

```py
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.filters
[('default', None, <class 'DeprecationWarning'>, '__main__', 0),
('ignore', None, <class 'DeprecationWarning'>, None, 0),
('ignore', None, <class 'PendingDeprecationWarning'>, None, 0),
('ignore', None, <class 'ImportWarning'>, None, 0),
('ignore', None, <class 'ResourceWarning'>, None, 0)]
```

FWIW, I found this by looking at the [code for `warnings.filterwarnings`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dec1e9346d82fa4a4761389c81d36ef9d01f332b/Lib/warnings.py#L130), which, via `_add_filter()`, references a `filters` global variable imported from the C module `_warnings`.